# Sum values from various lines in a file

Tags: shell

structureA is occuring multiple times in a file and I have to sum the values of parameter1 separately under numUnitsA, numUnitsB, numUnitsC for all occurance of structureA.

```
structureA {
    numUnitsA {
        parameter1 = 2
    }    
    numUnitsB {
        parameter1 = 4
    }    
    numUnitsC {
        parameter1 = 3
    }    
}
```

I use the below to get the values but how to sum them such as :

```
numUnitsA parameter1=6
numUnitsB parameter1=9
numUnitsC parameter1=9
```

code:

```
while read -r line
do
if grep -q "parameter1" "$filename"; then
   echo $(awk 'BEGIN{FS="="}{print $2}' )
fi
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F'= *' '/parameter1/ {
    if (++numUnit % 3 == 1) {par1 += $2}
    else if (numUnit % 3 == 2) {par2 += $2}
    else {par3 += $2}
}
END {print "numUnitsA parameter1=" par1
     print "numUnitsA parameter1=" par2
     print "numUnitsA parameter1=" par3}' "$filename"
```

No reason for the loop really. This will take the file as argument and look for occurrences of "numUnitX", get the next line and add the value to the total value corresponding with X. In the end it will print totals.

**Alternative answer:**

```
$ cols=$(($(grep parameter1 $filename | wc -l)/3))
$ grep parameter1 "$filename" | sed 's/.*= //' | pr -ts"+" --columns "$cols" | bc
```

This will get all values and then paste Unit A, B and C values next to each other on separate lines, separated by a '+' and calculate the sums using `bc`. The output is three lines, containing the totals for Units A, B and C respectively.

**Update**
Answer now works if parameter doesn't immediately follow the `numUnits` tag.

**Explanation**

**awk** is a program that divides a file into records (think of these as rows, even though they can be multiple rows) and fields (think of these as columns, with the previous remark still valid). The separation of these records and fields can be defined by the user but the default separators are a newline for the records and a tab for the fields. So the file structure is defined like this:

```
record1: field1    field2 spaces allowed    field 3
record2: this record has only one field

record4: the previous line was an empty record
record5: in awk you can refer to fields using $1, $2, $3. like this:
$1 in your code means this field    $2 in code this field    $3    $4
record7: $0 is the variable for the entire record!
```

The fields can be addressed using `$1`, `$2` etc., the special `$0` refers to the entire record. Two simple examples to illustrate. First we print the entire file, rendering the script equivalent to `cat`: `awk '{print} file' or`awk '{print $0}' file`. A second example changes every record (i.e. line as default) to the literal string`don't mock awk`:`awk '{$0 = "don'\'' mock awk"}' file`. Note the special care to output a`'`.

**Builtins** Some powerful awk builtin variables are available at our disposal, some are explained below.

- `FS` The field separator, default `FS = "\t"`
- `RS` The record separator, default `RS = "\n"`
- `OFS` Output field separator, default `OFS = " "`
- `ORS` Output record separator, default `ORS = "\n"`
- `NR` Current record number, at the end this is the number of records in the file.
- `NF` Number of fields in this record.
- `FILENAME` The file name of the file being processed.

These are very useful variables, when printing the output field separator `OFS` will automatically be inserted. Following sample code prints the first two fields of the first line, separated by a single space (the `OFS` gets inserted by using a space). `awk 'NR == 1 {print $1, $2}' file`.

**Structure** A basic awk structure is as follows:

```
awk -F'= ' '
# this is a comment (starting with #)
# begin clause
BEGIN {
    # do stuff BEFORE parsing the file
    FS = "= +"    # this is also achieved using the -F flag above
    ... 
}
/some regex/ {
    # code here will be executed if record contains 'some regex'
    # example: count number of lines that match this regex
    count++   # increment count with one
}
NR == 1 {
    # code here will only be executed on the first record
}
{
    # code right here will always be executed (i.e. for every record)
    # note the regex is missing => match every record
    ...
}
# add more clauses to match certain records before the end clause:
END {
    # execute code AFTER all files (you can read multiple files) have been parsed
    print count   # print number of records containing our regex
}' path/to/some/file_to_parse /another/path/to/another/file
```

Basically code wrapped in curly braces is executed if the preceding boolean returns true, whether it's a regex being found in the record (`/regex notation/`) or a logical comparison. When a condition lacks, the code will always be executed.

**Solution Code analyzed**

As you see, we don't have a BEGIN clause and only one record clause. We are looking for records, lines in our case, containing the literal string 'parameter1'. Which are exactly the lines containing the values we'd like to sum up.

We have set the field separator as the regex `= +` meaning an equal sign and one or more spaces. Note that for the records we're interested in, this means we have two records:

```
        paramter1 = 4
      field1     |||field 2,
```

this means `$2` now refers to `4`. Note that `$2` would be empty in the following record: `paramter1=4` since there is no space after the equal sign.

Now we have a switch of cases:

1. `numUnit` is equivalent to 1 modulo 3
2. `numUnit` is equivalent to 2 modulo 3
3. `numUnit` is equivalent to 3 modulo 3.

Note that we first have `if (++numUnit ...`, this will increment the variable `numUnit` before the expression is evaluated (so before the if checks the condition). As you can see, awk is not strongly typed so no need to declare `numUnit` first. At the first increase awk will just assume it's a zero because you try to add something to it and he doesn't know what it is.

So `numUnit` increases each time we find a record containing `paramter1`. Since the first time `numUnit` is evaluated to 1, then follows the pattern 1 2 0 1 2 0 ...´ and the ´numUnit´ pattern is `numUnitA numUnitB numUnitC numUnitA numUnitB ...`, you can see that each of these cases handles all and only records of one type. Each case will now add the value of the parameter to it's total (as you can now easily see in the code).

Finally we end the awk script by printing out info, remember that this only gets executed once, after all records have been read. This should be clear.

I strongly suggest reading up on awk, it's a very powerful scripting language allowing many high level programming language constructions. It may seem hard at first but it's totally worth the effort!

Comment: Thanks @ShellFish. The alternative answer searches for parameter1 , hence works irrespective of the position of parameter1 in the file. Can you suggest any modification in the first script to do the same.

Comment: @user2610 You are right, I fixed the issue. Of course the program won't work as it's supposed to if in some struct numUnitsB precedes numUnitsA. If this can happen I'll have to add a few more lines.

Comment: Thanks again@ShellFish.Its working fine. Will you please share the logic used in the script. I am new to scripting.

Comment: @user2610 I added an in-depth explanation of awk in general and an analysis of the used code. Happy scripting!